# how do i move the elements to the right by one in an array

Tags: c++

I need to insert a value into my array without using vector library. The way inserted it is by replacing the number at the index into which i wanna insert the number. I need to insert a number to an arbitrary index and move everything after the index to the right by keeping all the values. I tried doing it by creating a new array, but unfortunately no good..

```
    void Vector::insert(int value, int index) 
    {

      //initializing array to copy from index
      int* new_arr = new int[current];

      //copying everything from given index to the end
      for(int i = 0; i < current; i++){
          if((arr[index+1]) != NULL){
        new_arr[i] = arr[index + i];
        }
      }   
      //replaces the given value at the given index
      arr[index] = value;      

      //copying before and after the index into one array
      int* total_arr = new int[current+1];
      //before index
      for (int i = 0; i < index; i++){
        total_arr[i] = arr[i];
      }
      //after index
      for(int i = index; i< current+1; i++){
        total_arr[i] = new_arr[i];
      }
    
      capacity += 1;
      arr = new int[capacity];
      for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++){
        arr[i] = total_arr[i];
      }    
   
      //replaces the given value at the given index
      arr[index] = value;      

      //copying before and after the index into one array
      int* total_arr = new int[current+1];
      //before index
      for (int i = 0; i < index; i++){
        total_arr[i] = arr[i];
      }
      //after index
      for(int i = index; i< current+1; i++){
        total_arr[i] = new_arr[i];
      }
       for(int i = 0; i<current+1; i++){
         std::cout<<total_arr[i]<<std::endl;
      }
     for(int i = 0; i<capacity+1; i++){
         std::cout<<total_arr[i]<<std::endl;
     }
       capacity += 1;
       arr = new int[capacity];
      for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++){
         arr[i] = total_arr[i];
       }

    }
```

Comment: ? [`std::rotate()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate)?

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks too long and complicated.

Not knowing the specification of your class, the implemention should be something like this (assuming `arr` is the pointer to the data array and `current` is the number of elements in the array):

```
void Vector::insert(int value, int index) 
{
    int* new_arr = new int[current+1];

    // positions of elements before insertion won't change
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) new_arr[i] = arr[i];

    // the element to insert
    new_arr[index] = value;

    // positions of elements after insertion will move by one
    for (i = index; i < current; i++) new_arr[i + 1] = arr[i];

    // change the arrays
    int* old_arr = arr;
    arr = new_arr;
    delete[] old_arr;
    current++;
}
```